# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException using WebDriver Driver=new Chrome() and maximize Chrome browser window using selenium script

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How to maximize Chrome browser window using selenium script?
This is my code:

```
package newpackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

 WebDriver Driver=new Chrome();
    Driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    Driver.manage().window().maximize();

}
}
```

However, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at newpackage.MyClass.main(MyClass.java:10)
```

Answer (score 2):

To work with Selenium 3.4.0 you need to download the latest chromedriver 2.29 from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) and update your Google Chrome to latest release of 58.x. Save the chromedriver in your system and provide the absolute path in your code through `System.setProperty` as below.

Now, the constructor for initializing *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome Browser* is as follows:

- `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();`
- `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);`

*Note*: The method is **`ChromeDriver()`** but not `Chrome()` which have caused **java.lang.NullPointerException**

Finally, to maximize Chrome browser window using selenium script you need to take help of `ChromeOptions` class as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("start-maximized");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.navigate().to("https://google.com");
    //do your actions
    driver.quit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the script you have written the Driver object is null. Try instantiate the Driver properly by using Chromedriver.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "c:\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
Driver.get("http://www.google.com");
Driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.AddArguments("disable-infobars");
    options.AddArguments("--start-maximized");
    options.AddArguments("--disable-extensions");
    var chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

use driver.manage().window().fullscreen(); instead

It should work.

Comment: A short answer is welcome, however it won't provide much value to the latter users who are trying to understand what's going on behind the problem. Please spare some time to explain what's the real issue to cause the problem and how to solve. Thank you ~

Comment: You are absolutely correct. But being honest with you, I am just a learner. I never code or automated anything in my life until now. Just did lots of research and practice to start automating stuff. I will remember your advice and try to come up with reasons why stuff is not working instead finding another way, Thanks.